# Multiple inserts with spservices .72

Tags: spservices

I have tried to insert multiple items in to list

```
var s=[];
$.each(f, function(){
 var l = [];
 l.x="pp";
 l.y="ll";
s.push(l)
})


$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({               
                listName: "xxxx",                
                batchCmd: "New",
                valuepairs: s,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

                    console.log(xData.responseXML);
                }});
```

nothing works, I don't get error but an empty results tag
    is there a working way t do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert multiple new items into a SharePoint List then you have to use [SPServices.SPAddMultipleListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/workitem/8719) .

In your code you are using [SPUpdateMultipleListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems), its used to  to update multiple items in a list based upon some common characteristic or metadata criteria.

If you want to insert new items into a SharePoint list using SPServices, you can use the following code,

```
$.fn.SPServices.SPAddMultipleListItems = function(options) {

    var opt = $.extend({}, {
        webURL: "",         // [Optional] URL of the target Web.  If not specified, the current Web is used.
        listName: "",       // The list to operate on.
        batchCmd: "New",    // The operation to perform. By default, New.
        valuepairs: [],     // Valuepairs for the update in the form [[fieldname1, fieldvalue1], [fieldname2, fieldvalue2]...]
        completefunc: null, // Function to call on completion of rendering the change.
        debug: false        // If true, show error messages;if false, run silent
    }, options);

    var i;
    var fieldNum;
    var batch = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>";
    for (i = 0; i < opt.valuepairs.length; i&#43;&#43;) {
        batch &#43;= "<Method ID='" &#43; i &#43; "' Cmd='" &#43; opt.batchCmd &#43; "'>";
        batch &#43;= "<Field Name='" &#43; opt.valuepairs[i][0] &#43; "'>" &#43; opt.valuepairs[i][3] &#43; "</Field>";
        batch &#43;= "</Method>";
    }
    batch &#43;= "</Batch>";

    // Call UpdateListItems        
$().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL: opt.webURL,
        listName: opt.listName,
        updates: batch,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            // If present, call completefunc when all else is done
            if (opt.completefunc !== null) {
                opt.completefunc();
            }
        }
    });

}; // End $.fn.SPServices.SPAddMultipleListItems
```

[Source](http://spservices.codeplex.com/workitem/8719)

Comment: For everyone passing by: as a copy and paste of an already bad formatted and encoded piece of code, "&#43;" is equal to a plus (+) sign.